# How to pass timezone in getEvents(startTime, endTime) method in google appscript?

Tags: google-apps-script

I am fetching events from google calendar using getEvents(startTime, endTime) method. https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/calendar/calendar#getEvents(Date,Date) According to this documentation on Google, we can pass the timezone in which we are sending start & end date but how? That is not mentioned . So how can we pass timezone while fetching events from Google Calendar using method getEvents(startTime, endTime) in apps-script

Answer (score 1):

The Date type handles timezones; see more informations here : https://developers.google.com/google-ads/scripts/docs/features/dates

You can use for example `getTimezoneOffset()` to retrieve the timezone of a given Date.